# Can you use HIbernate fetch type LAZY but use EAGER sometimes

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a class **Song** that contains a lazy association to **CoverArt** class

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "recNo")
private List<CoverArt> coverArts;
```

That is fine, I don't usually need the CoverArt object, but sometimes I do

1. For SQL efficiency
2. Because I want to use the Song class on the EventThread, and user may try to access the CoverArt outside of HibernateSession, and so it will fail

So How would I modify a method such as

```
public static List<Song> getSongsWithCoverArtFromDatabase(Session session, List<Integer> ids)
{
      Criteria c = session
              .createCriteria(Song.class)
              .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
              .add(Restrictions.in("recNo", ids));
      List<Song> songs = c.list();
      return songs;
}
```

so that it retrieved  CoverArt for each song

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setFetchMode` of `Criteria` to set the fetch mode during runtime as below,

```
Criteria c = session
              .createCriteria(Song.class)
              .setFetchMode("coverArts", FetchMode.EAGER)
              .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
              .add(Restrictions.in("recNo", ids));
```

For more information, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FetchMode.html and https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-set-the-fetch-mode-for-criteria-association/

Comment: Thankyou that works, but seems that FetchMode.EAGER has been deprcated for FetchMode.JOIN which is maybe why I struggled to find an answer